# How to add a new row of text box and drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently working on a rails project.

I have a text_field and a select_tag on the same row. I want a new row of text box and drop down list to be created whenever I have at least one character typed in the current text box. But I'm not sure how to do so. I assume I'd need to use jquery? But I'm still a newbie with web programming...

Please help! Many thanks!!!

Comment: Your solution could be handled with JavaScript or jQuery, with some planning, the only problem is that you will not instantly have a Sticky Form. Meaning, you will lose value upon submission. Therefore, you might consider an iframe that submits the form in your `contentWindow`  onkeyup so you can hold your values for your sever. I could do this in PHP, with JavaScript, but don't know ruby-on-rails. Hopefully, my comment will make you aware of the Stick Form issue.

Comment: Thanks! How would you do this in PHP? Maybe I can reference a bit from that?

Answer (score 0):

You'd add fields and then apply a hidden value to them using jQuery's document ready function.  Then apply a keyup function to the existing field you want it to trigger off of that calls show on the hidden item.

Here's the jquery I used in a wordpress page to do exactly that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fieldtohide").hide();
  $("#nonhiddenfield").keyup(function() {
    $("#fieldtohide").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the Programmer knows how many `text` and `select` fields they will need.

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought of that.